# Where does backup goes, & how much memory it takes?

Tags: 14.04, backup, home-directory, storage

I have an issue with Ubuntu 14.04, & I think that it's because of the backup storage!
The issue is that the available storage in my home directory is getting small without using by the time.
I want to know where the backup files goes, how much memory does it take, & what if I want to direct it's storage!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which application are you using to backup?

Comment: The default one with Ubuntu, named "Backups" I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the stock backup app then you can set its destination location

most backup apps let you set the location actually

Comment: no prob.
try playing around with the settings when you try a new app.
saves a lot of time if you ask me